# Append blobs to url and show

Tags: javascript

What I am trying to achieve is to have "stream" of blobs from my socket and append it to a video.
Currently, I have something like

```
const socket = io();
const videoGrid = document.getElementById("video-grid");
const video = document.createElement("video");
video.muted = true;

videoGrid.append(video);
let blobArray = [];

socket.on("view-stream-10", (data) => {
  blobArray.push(
    new Blob([new Uint8Array(data)], {
      type: "video/x-matroska;codecs=avc1,opus",
    })
  );
  let currentTime = video.currentTime;

  let blob = new Blob(blobArray, { type: "video/x-matroska;codecs=avc1,opus" });
  video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  video.currentTime = currentTime;
  video.play();
});
```

It works but there are some problems that video stops for a X ms at the point where new blob beeing created and url is changed and it's beeing so visible.

Is there any better way?